# Out come of code not as expected

Tags: vhdl

I am working in Xilinx webpack with VHDL and a Nexys 2 FPGA and am trying to get used to making modular code. So my project consists of 3 short files: main.vhd, Adder_4bit.vhd, and constraints.ucf. My code compiles fine but LED 6 lights up and nothing responds to any changes to the switches like it supposed to. Here are my files:

main.vhd

```
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity main is
    Port ( switches : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           LEDs : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end main;

architecture Behavioral of main is
COMPONENT Adder_4bit
PORT(
    x : IN std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    y : IN std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    cin : IN std_logic;          
    cout : OUT std_logic;
    sum : OUT std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    gp : OUT std_logic;
    gg : OUT std_logic
    );
END COMPONENT;

signal zero : STD_LOGIC;

begin

Inst_Adder_4bit: Adder_4bit PORT MAP(
        x => switches(7 downto 4),
        y => switches(3 downto 0),
        cin => zero,
        cout => LEDs(7),
        sum => LEDs(3 downto 0),
        gp => LEDs(6),
        gg => LEDs(5)
    );
LEDs(4) <= '0';
end Behavioral;
```

Adder_4bit.vhd

```
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity Adder_4bit is
    Port ( x : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           y : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
           cout : out  STD_LOGIC;
           sum : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
              gp : out STD_LOGIC;
              gg : out STD_LOGIC);
end Adder_4bit;

architecture Behavioral of Adder_4bit is
    signal p        : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    signal g        : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
    signal iCarry : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);

begin
    p <= x or y;
    g <= x and y;
    iCarry(0) <= cin;
    iCarry(1) <= g(0) or (p(0) and iCarry(0));
    iCarry(2) <= g(1) or (p(1) and iCarry(1));
    iCarry(3) <= g(2) or (p(2) and iCarry(2));
    iCarry(4) <= g(3) or (p(3) and iCarry(3));
    sum(0) <= x(0) xor y(0) xor iCarry(0);
    sum(1) <= x(1) xor y(1) xor iCarry(1);
    sum(2) <= x(2) xor y(2) xor iCarry(2);
    sum(3) <= x(3) xor y(3) xor iCarry(3);
    cout <= iCarry(4);
    gp <= p(0) and p(1) and p(2) and p(3);
    gg <= g(3) or (g(2) and p(3)) or (g(1) and p(2) and p(3)) or (g(0) and p(1) and p(2) and p(3));

end Behavioral;
```

And finally constraints.ucf

```
NET switches(7) LOC = "R17";
NET switches(6) LOC = "N17";
NET switches(5) LOC = "L13";
NET switches(4) LOC = "L14";
NET switches(3) LOC = "K17";
NET switches(2) LOC = "K18";
NET switches(1) LOC = "H18";
NET switches(0) LOC = "G18";

NET LEDs(7) LOC = "R4";
NET LEDs(6) LOC = "F4";
NET LEDs(5) LOC = "P15";
NET LEDs(4) LOC = "E17";
NET LEDs(3) LOC = "K14";
NET LEDs(2) LOC = "K15";
NET LEDs(1) LOC = "J15";
NET LEDs(0) LOC = "J14";

#NET LCD_a0 LOC = "F17";
#NET LCD_a1 LOC = "H17";
#NET LCD_a2 LOC = "C18";
#NET LCD_a3 LOC = "F15";

#NET LCD_A LOC = "L18";
#NET LCD_B LOC = "F18";
#NET LCD_C LOC = "D17";
#NET LCD_D LOC = "D16";
#NET LCD_E LOC = "G14";
#NET LCD_F LOC = "J17";
#NET LCD_G LOC = "H14";
#NET LCD_DP LOC = "C17";

#NET clock LOC = "B8";
#NET "clock" TNM_NET = clock;
#TIMESPEC TS_clk = PERIOD "clock" 4 ns HIGH 50%;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a first step simply wire the switches straight to the LEDs via the FPGA. If that works as expected, then add on to that. (Wire the LEDs to p and g for example). THEN try the current design.

Comment: What will happen in your FPGA when you don't assign a value to the signal zero in main.vhd?  I a std_logic simulation it will propagate 'X's like crazy.  In the FPGA  it will float to '1', float to '0' or what?

Comment: I thought it floats low, but I can try to assign a 0 to it, but I'd still get some sort of change when I move switches I would think. And to Brian, I did do the wiring the switches directly to the LEDs, and that worked, so as far as I can see it's not a hardware issue or anything.

Comment: Does it work in simulation first?

Comment: I converted main.vhd into a testbench with minimal changes and range a few test cases.  Looked like the ALU was getting the right answer and the carryout and gp looked right.  I think the problem is likely in the tool chain.

Comment: So if the problem is in the tool chain, what would I need to do to fix it if there was anything I could do?

Comment: There's something different between switches to LEDS and putting an adder in between.

Comment: In keeping with Paul's answer the simulation I did was with zero intialized to '0'.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with how I turned my CLA Adder into a module. So it's something about the module definition or something that is messing up my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my issue. It turns out that Xilinx ISE produced two bit files, one for each VHD file. So I had an Adder_4bit.bit and a main.bit file in my project folder. In my code Adder_4bit is instantiated in main and so I needed to upload main.bit into my FPGA, but I instead uploaded the Adder_4bit.bit file, the one that made sense to me since my project is also called Adder_4bit.

In short make sure you upload the main bit file and not the component bit file.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to a synthesiser right now, but I believe the problem is that you have not initialised your zero value.

When the signal is not defined, your optimizer might optimize things out that you did not intend.

Try declaring your zero signal constant or wiring your cin to '0'.

(I would have just left a comment, but it seems you need more rep to do that)

Comment: I just tried both declaring zero as '0' and hard wiring cin to '0'. Neither of them fixed the problem. If functions exactly the same.